Solvable Lie groups decompose as a semidirect product
I am searching for a reference or proof to the following fact (asserted at the top of page 2 here).
Let $G$ be a connected, solvable Lie group. Then $G = L \rtimes K$ satisfying

$K$ compact
$L$ solvable and normal in $G$
There is some compact normal $T \subset L$ so that $L/T$ is simply connected.

This fact does not appear on wikipedia's list of Lie group decompositions. Most resources I can find are about decompositions of or into semisimple lie groups (my $G$ is solvable). This question gives a decomposition of $G$ into one parameter subgroups (isomorphic to $S^1$ or $\mathbb{R}$) and seems quite close to what I want, but there's no guarantee that those tori are normal.
I think that I am missing some general fact about the structure of solvable Lie groups. Any help/references are appreciated.
